# Is there a free Warren Abstract Machine implementation for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, implementation, abstract-machine

I have done a thorough search but were still in vain.

Reference:

[Warren abstract machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warren_abstract_machine) (Wikipedia).

Question:

Is there any such implementation (open source)?

If not, I am enclined to accept an answer for a solution wrapping a good one written in other language (Dll and/or obj files to link, I know of [Prolog.NET](http://prolog.codeplex.com/): Please don't suggest it).

Comment: http://www.amzi.com/AmziPrologLogicServer/white_papers/amzi_overview.php   ?

Comment: @J: Interesting, unfortunately proprietary. The url link to the [Delphi full source code sample](http://www.amzi.com/download/demos/delphi_informant_sample.zip) is broken.

Comment: yes, it's proprietary.  Your question wasn't clear on whether you were after a practical solution or something open source so I suggested it.  They do offer a source-code licence at the bottom of the main download page.

Comment: @J: Please notice it's stated "Free" in the header. I'll edit the body to make it more clear. Thank you for suggesting it.

Comment: aah, sorry.  Sometimes I don't notice these things.  Apologies, my fault.

Comment: @J: Your suggestion is valuable. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

My graduation work (1987) was to define the macroexpansion for Prolog and test its possible benefits. My target was the WAM. I had the source code of WAM in DEC-10 assembly language, but unfortunately I had no DEC-10 (neither physical nor emulated), so I had to implement a compiler from the WAM language to TurboPascal v3 as a side work. As far as I remember, my implementation was not complete, but enough for what I had to do. I'd be surprised if, almost five years after having posted this question, you found this contribution (so small, so late) useful; however, if you do, just post an answer and I'll gladly send you my source code. I wrote it, I can gladly donate my rights to the public domain.

Comment: So nice of you considering a public release. Please do, I think mostly of a github repository...